# maven cannot find symbol symbol: class ProxyServer-browsermob

Tags: java, maven, selenium, browsermob, selenide

I am using the following example to add proxy **browsermob** with Selenide and Selenium.
I used the this [link](http://www.automationace.com/2014/04/measuring-performance-with-browsermob-proxy-using-selenium-webdriver.html).

I run it with Eclipse and I a successfully running it. but when I tried it with **Maven**. I have the following Error:

> location: package net.lightbody.bmp.proxymaven cannot find symbol
>   symbol: class ProxyServer

My Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Replace the `browsermob-core` dependency with `browsermob-core-legacy`, and your code will compile and run.

**Long answer:** BrowserMob Proxy has been almost completely rewritten using LittleProxy, which is faster, more stable, and supports more features than the legacy code you're currently using. I highly recommend upgrading to the new implementation; see the [readme on github](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#changes-since-200) for information on the new interface.

At the very least, I would encourage you to use the "legacy adapter" class that wraps the old ProxyServer interface with a LittleProxy implementation. See the [readme](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#changes-since-the-21-beta-series) for details.